How to migrate datadog Gauge() metrics to new relic ObservableGauge()?
I am currently in the process of moving away from datadog and migrating to new relic. I have a metric called Gauge() which needs to be migrated to ObservableGaug() metric.

String tag = (fileSizeMB <=1) ? "0MB-2MB": (fileSizeMB <= 4) ? "2MB-4MB": (fileSizeMB <= 6) ? "4MB-6MB": "6MB+";


_dogStatsd.Gauge("test", tags: new[] {"size":{tag}"});

